# how to join two large datasets in spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I can currently working on large dataset , one is like 670Gb parquet with snappy file with 200 unique keys , 10000 partitions and other data sets are also large with 100+ keys and 200 partitions  but can not be used as broadcast table in join.

```
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4000
--conf spark.executor.memory=24g
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=2048
--executor-cores 1
```

I can have max 28 Gb container per node other wise yarn kills it . I have 570 node cluster with 128Gb ram.
How should i process dataset to join operation.

```
[Stage 3:>                                                   (68 + 717) / 10136]
```

Now i am not sure why i am getting 717 active task as i am running only one executor per node(--executor-cores 1 ), can you help me in understanding this.
Please suggest how should i go with this join operation because if i am correct data per key is large enough that i cannot be fit in one node. 
I am getting error

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
17/07/16 02:49:10 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Dropping SparkListenerEvent because no remaining room in event queue. This likely means one of the SparkListeners is too slow and cannot keep up with the rate at which tasks are being started by the scheduler.
```

Comment: Try partitioning both datasets by the same columns and joining them after

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto I have tried that but 675Gb dataset has only 200 unique key due to with data per partition is very large may be it does not fits in one executor.